# ExAC Browser: What does a "dubious variant annotation" mean?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, human-genetics, population-genetics, database

[image: screenshot of the ExAC database in a web browser]

I am studying a protein in the ExAC browser. However it is flagged with a "LoF flag". What exactly counts as a "dubious" variant in ExAC.

I couldn't find any further information neither at the variant's page nor in the FAQs.

[Link to ExAC browser](http://exac.broadinstitute.org/).

[Link to variant site](http://exac.broadinstitute.org/variant/14-45636324-C-CG) (This is a bad example, because there is a multi-allelic warning, but this is the variant shown in the picture)

Further links to variants with LC LoF flag:

[14-45636336-C-T](http://exac.broadinstitute.org/variant/14-45636336-C-T)

[14-45636346-C-CTA](http://exac.broadinstitute.org/variant/14-45636346-C-CTA)

Comment: Link please. I've never heard of it and shouldn't have to search.

Comment: This is interesting. Could you also show exactly what the variant page says?

Comment: I have asked for the definition of a dubious variant in the ExAC browser, or a source where I can find that definition. I can not imagine a clearer question. Pls don't mark my question as unclear on the sole ground that you don't know ExAC or can not answer the question.

Comment: It wasn't the unfamiliarity with the site and software, it was the fact that the original question had a result that didn't have enough information to reproduce the problem. If you could provide a link to your search that reported the dubious annotation (and _maybe_ some additional context) I think initiating a reopen would be successful. Note that @David did not vote to close.

Comment: Not sure if this is related but theres been an effort recently to validate some of the predicted functional annotations. Its possible that the flag relates to inconsistencies between predicted function (LoF) and actual function in cell line systems. btw for reproducibility, [this](http://exac.broadinstitute.org/transcript/ENST00000556036) is the link to the page (press LoF button above export tables)

Comment: LC LoF stands for low quality loss of function. The variant is predicted to be a loss of function but has been filtered by LOFTEE. If you click on the transcripts drop down under annotation next to FANCM you'll see that at least one functional prediction is filtered. The [FAQ](http://exac.broadinstitute.org/faq) gives more details in to how the filter criteria for LoF was set. Unfortunately, the question is on hold so I cannot post this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly speaking you expect more or less uniform coverage for reads. So if you see a systematic difference in quality scores or coverage for minor and major alleles or for forward and reverse strand, it could be an SNV, but most likely it is a technical issue. That's a 'dubious variant'.

A lot of such biases are described in "[Genotype and SNP calling from next-generation sequencing data](http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v12/n6/full/nrg2986.html)":

> Other types of filtering based on deviations from the HWE — generally
>   low-quality scores, systematic differences in quality scores for major
>   and minor alleles, aberrant LD patterns, extreme read depths, strand
>   bias, and so on — can also help to improve the accuracy of genotype
>   and SNP calling. The appropriate filters depend on the sequencing
>   protocol and the upstream analyses. For example, a site with strand
>   bias (where a disproportional number of plus and minus strands are
>   observed) could be an indication of a problematic site that is more
>   error prone and should be filtered out. However, if the sequencing has
>   been performed on captured sequences, such as those used for exome
>   capturing, then the bias might not be an indication of a problematic
>   site but rather an artefact of the capture array.

**Update**
I've just received an answer from ExAC:

> The "LC LoF” means that the variant was marked as a low confidence
>   loss of function variant. If you click on the “Transcripts” dropdown
>   on the variant page it will show the reason why the variant is of low
>   confidence for that transcript. In this case it was flagged as
>   “END_TRUNC”. An explanation of the LoF filters can be found here:
>   https://github.com/konradjk/loftee

Comment: You are describing a dubious variant CALL. I think a dubious variant ANNOTATION refers to the classification as Loss of Function (LoF). 
Maybe there is an inconsistency in ExAC, but I'm not sure. Are you?